# Prepend text to beginning of file name using powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to prepend some text onto the beginning of a filename using powershell on a Windows 2008 R2 server.  I'm moving the files to another server and trying to use Rename-Item.  Below are three ways I've tried.

```
    $prefix = "Voucher_"
    $TestFile = "\\fileshare\ftp\Test\M1HPVWZR" 

    $DateStamp = get-date -uformat "%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S"
    Rename-Item -Path $TestFile -NewName $($prefix)$TestFile$DateStamp
    Rename-Item -Path $TestFile -NewName ($TestFile$DateStamp -replace "M1H","Voucher_M1H")     
    Rename-Item -Path $TestFile -NewName {"M1HPVWZR_" + $TestFile$DateStamp}
```

Using the same logic it does work when I append $prefix as shown below and it works fine if I just 
change the name to $TestFile$DateStamp, also shown below.

```
    Rename-Item -Path $TestFile -NewName $TestFile$DateStamp$prefix
    Rename-Item -Path $TestFile -NewName $TestFile$DateStamp$prefix
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. - Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? Every question/problem brought up in this question seems to already be answered later in the question.

Comment: Hi Jessie, I was trying to prepend the text to a file name and was unsuccessful.  It made it even more confusing when I was able to append it using the same format. When I tried the replace option there was a syntactical error and Drew spotted it.  What a relief, I must have tried 20 different ways to do it and was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the wrong syntax. Either of the below will work.

```
# Encapsulating the variables in quotes will expand them and treat them as one for the -replace
Rename-Item -Path $TestFile -NewName ("$TestFile$DateStamp" -replace 'M1H','Voucher_M1H')

# Combines two string variables with +
Rename-Item -Path $TestFile -NewName ($TestFile+$DateStamp -replace 'M1H','Voucher_M1H')
```

Comment: Many thanks, that is exactly what I needed and I'm up and running! Thanks again!